# Is there a way of showing names instead of the ID in a SELECT SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I got this table for a project [table image here]

[image: 1]

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    job_title_id INTEGER,
    manager_id INTEGER,    
    CONSTRAINT fk_role FOREIGN KEY (job_title_id) REFERENCES roles(id) ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_manager FOREIGN KEY (manager_id) REFERENCES employees(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

I'm trying instead of showing the manager id, show its name, can I do that considering that they are on the same table?

SELECT employees.id, employees.first_name, employees.last_name, employees.manager_id, roles.job_title FROM employees LEFT JOIN roles ON employees.job_title_id = roles.id;

This is the SELECT query I'm trying so far but whenever I try to display the managers name instead of the id it doesn't work

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  What have you tried?

Comment: You can join the table with itself.